# How to make only textbox less wide?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want the text boxes to be less wide, maybe half the size? How would I do this? [Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR410.png)

I tried using col-xs-5 but that would ruin the vertical alignment.

```html
<h2>
Add User
</h2>

<div class="user">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :first_name, :class => 'col-form-label' %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, :placeholder => "First name", :class => 'form-control', :required => 'required' %><br>
      <%= f.label :last_name, :class => 'col-form-label' %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name", :class => 'form-control', :required => 'required' %><br>
      <%= f.label :email, :class => 'col-form-label' %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email", :class => 'form-control', :required => 'required' %><br>
      <%= f.label :password, :class => 'col-form-label' %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password", :class => 'form-control', :required => 'required' %><br>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Confirm password", :class => 'form-control', :required => 'required' %><br>

      <%= f.submit "Add", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.container-fluid is a width of 100%.

So wrap the form in another div inside the container-fluid and set a max-width to like 500px. That should squeeze the form smaller. Play around with that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added <div style = "max-width: 630px;"> right under the container-fluid div and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Apply a width (or max-width) to the text boxes using CSS. That will only impact those elements and not the container around them.